# Update PHP version of Wordpress (internal hosting)

Tags: php

I apologize if this question has already been asked; I'm very new here.

The company I work for has an internally hosted Wordpress page and is running PHP v5.6.31. We believe this is causing functionality issues with our Wordpress Dashboard and various plugins. We need to update our PHP to at least 7.x.x. I've searched the Internet high and low, and only found articles on how to update PHP via your web hosting provider. I have no idea how to do this and don't want to look more incompetent than I already do at this job.

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It has to be done through the hosting control panels and the 'How To' depends on the host.  It's actually not a huge process at all, you just have to get into your hosting admin and find the section within there (all of the admin consoles are a bit different) and then you just select the PHP version you want and within a few seconds it's done.  Where is the site hosted?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tony. The site is hosted on one of our file servers. All of the related posts I've seen point towards the WordPress Dashboard, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I've never heard of updating your PHP version through your WP Dashboard.  Do you have an IT department?  Who's responsible for maintaining the servers?  Share one of the links here if you like.